# Change authoring information on multiple nodes

Tags: datetime, nodes

How can I change the publication date for multiple nodes at the same time without to individually edit each node?

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I haven't found an option in VBO to change publication date...?